# Studying for Actuarial exams

Tags: combinatorics

A Store has 80 modems in its inventory, 30 coming from source A and the remainder from source B. Of the modems from source A, 20% are defective. Of the modems from Source B, 8% are defective. Calculate the probability that exactly two out of a renadom sample of five modems from the store's inventory are defective.

Not even sure where to start with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** How many bad modems are there altogether?

If $N$ is the total number of modems, and $B$ is the number of bad ones, how many ways are there to choose $5$ modems? How many ways are there to choose $2$ bad and $3$ good?

Comment: Well, I know there's 10 total defective modems out of the 80. Is it something like (80 choose 5)*(5 choose 2)*(1/8)^2.

Comment: We are sampling **without** replacement. There are $\binom{10}{2}\binom{70}{3}$ ways to choose $2$ bad and $3$ good. Divide by $\binom{80}{5}$.